# scripts in /etc/rc.local not autorunning

Tags: linux, bash, shell, raspberry-pi

I have put some scripts to run in the rc.local file of my raspberry pi. The end of the rc.local file where I have added the scripts reads as follows:

```
sh /home/pi/HAS_system/execute/CAM.sh &
sh /home/pi/HAS_system/execute/VID.sh &
sh /home/pi/HAS_system/camera/stopvidcam.sh &
sh /home/pi/HAS_system/camera/autostopvidcam.sh &
#sh /home/pi/HAS_system/execute/FS.sh &
sh /home/pi/HAS_system/execute/GS.sh &
sh /home/pi/HAS_system/execute/HTS.sh &
sh /home/pi/HAS_system/execute/MS.sh &
#sh /home/pi/HAS_system/execute/RS.sh &
#sh /home/pi/HAS_system/execute/SS.sh &
sh /home/pi/HAS_system/execute/WC.sh &

exit 0
```

These scripts are used to monitor various services from the local web server. I am sure that the first four scripts, CAM.sh, VID.sh, stopvidcam.sh, and autostopvidcam.sh are running by accessing them through the web page, and finding that they are working as expected. However, the following scripts seem to not be working, GS.sh, HTS.sh, MS.sh and WC.sh. These scripts are supposed to send a mail and tweet on appropriate sensor trigger. I can run these manually from the command line as:

```
sudo sh /home/pi/HAS_system/execute/MS.sh &
```

and can check that the sensor triggers are working, but they are not working  from rc.local.

I tried checking if these processes are running in the background with

```
ps aux | grep "/home/pi/HAS_system/execute/MS.sh"
```

and found this result:

```
root       592  0.2  0.1   1912  1112 ?        S    17:04   0:09 sh /home/pi/HAS_system/execute/MS.sh
pi       30116  0.0  0.2   4280  1852 pts/0    S+   18:07   0:00 grep --color=auto /home/pi/HAS_system/execute/MS.sh
```

The first item definitely shows a process id for the script at the time of boot, but the triggers do not work.

The trigger codes (MS.sh, GS.sh, etc) are similar, coded as:

```
#!/bin/bash

dname=$(date +"%Y_%m_%d-%H_%M_%S")
code="MS"

while :
do
        new=$(sudo python /home/pi/HAS_system/sensor_check/MScheck.py)
        echo $new
        old=$(sudo bash /home/pi/HAS_system/data/data_reader.sh  /home/pi/HAS_system/data/sensor_data.ini $code)

        if [ "$new" != "$old" ]
        then
                curl -d "dname=$dname&sid=$code&val=$new" http://localhost/devcalls/updatesensorpanel.php
                sudo bash /home/pi/HAS_system/data/data_reader.sh  /home/pi/HAS_system/data/sensor_data.ini $code $new
        fi

        if [ "$new" = "Motion" ]
        then
                sudo python3 /home/pi/HAS_system/comm/tweet.py $new
                sudo python3 /home/pi/HAS_system/comm/mail.py $new
        fi
done
```

What exactly is going wrong here?

Comment: Could be a timing issue. If the scripts rely on any network services, if they aren't started before the scripts execute, you won't get the desired outcomes. You may need to add a sleep or two.

Comment: Btw.: `sh` is not `bash`.

Comment: Check this article regarding using sudo: https://askubuntu.com/questions/909024/how-to-run-script-in-rc-local